# Why there are 11 tabstops on a 80-column console?

Tags: terminal

You would assume that since each tab moves forward 8 columns by default, a 80-column console would have exactly 10 tab-stops. This can be disproved:

```
$ printf "1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t0\ta"
```

One would expect the output to be in 2 lines, because there are 10 tab-stops, taking the room of all 80 columns, plus a single charater, that is to be pushed to the next line. But the command produces a single output line in xterm, gnome-terminal and rxvt.

What happened is that the last tab-stop magically takes one character less space.

Meanwhile, expand(1) maintains that a tab's space is 8, thus

```
$ printf "1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t0\ta" | expand
```

would magically produce 2 lines on a 80-column console.

It seems a standard of some sort. But I just can't find a source by googling.

Tested in Linux only, but I am afraid this is shared by all unix.

Comment: None of those are consoles.  They are all GUI terminal emulators.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### There are only 9 tabstops on an 80-column console.

Let's expand upon the comment first.  You haven't actually tested *any* consoles.  Those are all GUI *terminal emulator* programs.  Fortunately, actual consoles (on Linux and FreeBSD at least) do also exhibit this behaviour.

But it's not the behaviour that you claim.  It doesn't demonstrate 11 tabstops.  It demonstrates 9.

To understand tabstops properly, you need to throw away the "They always expand to N spaces." idea.  If you have access to a mechanical typewriter with tabstops, then go and look at how it works (with tabs being set by protruding pins on the carriage).  Tabstops in terminals in the Unix and Linux worlds *work this way*.

(One can configure the line discipline to enact *soft* tabs, replacing tab characters in the output stream with space characters before they ever reach the terminal.  We're discussing *hard* tabs, executed by the terminal itself rather than by the line discipline, here though.  With hard tabs, a bone fide `TAB` character is sent to the terminal.  With soft tabs on, conversely, the behaviour that you describe doesn't occur in the first place.  Try setting `stty tab3` and see.)

As initialized, a terminal has *no tabstops set at all*.  Early on, `getty`, or the `reset` command or something akin (it varying as to system), outputs a series of space characters and escape sequences that *sets the tabstops* at particular columns.  Sometimes the columns and even the escape sequences are hardwired.  Most often, though, the command looks up the information in the termcap/terminfo database.  The terminfo capability giving the escape sequence for clearing all tabs is `tbc`; the `hts` capability gives the escape sequence for setting a tab at the current column; and the  `it` capability specifies the number of columns between tabstops by default.  For termcap, the equivalent capabilities are `it`, `ct`, and `st`.

The command obtains the terminal size (from the kernel, via a system call, or from another part of the terminfo/termcap record), looks at the number of columns, and repeatedly outputs `it` spaces followed by a `st` sequence for as many columns as it can, finally outputting a *carriage return* to return to column #0.  This is *exactly* the way that one sets a set of tabstops on many mechanical typewriters: space repeatedly to the next tabstop, hit the "set tabstop" lever to push a pin out, repeat until the right margin, push the carriage back to the left.

For an 80-column-wide terminal, with `it` given as 8 as it usually is, the command does this *nine* times, setting tabstops at columns 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, and 72.

There's no tabstop (barring a program bug) at column 0.  This is your first counting mistake.  There's also no tabstop in column 80, your second counting mistake.  "Why", you may ask, "is that?"  Firstly, it is because it is not possible to *be* in column 80 to set a tabstop.  The cursor goes from column 0 to column 79 on an 80-column terminal.

Secondly, one must think about the behaviour of the `TAB` character.  It does *not*, contrary to popular belief, expand to enough spaces to move to the next multiple of 8 columns.  Unix and Linux terminals work like mechanical typewriters, remember.  In the world of mechanical typewriters, the tab key moves the carriage until it is stopped by a tabstop pin or by the right margin.  (Some clever-clogs might mention *margin release* at this point.  This is something that mechanical typewriters have that Unix and Linux terminals have not, for obvious reasons.)

The `TAB` character on Unix and Linux terminals actually works *the very same way*.  In response to it, the terminal emits spaces until the next set tabstop *or the rightmost column* is reached.  And that's what's happening here.  When the cursor is in column 79, you can write as many `TAB` characters as you like, and nothing will happen.  There's no tabbing beyond the rightmost column.

The termcap/terminfo system allows settable hard tabs to be optional.  But the programs that you've tested with all provide an "xterm"-type terminal emulator.  (The escape sequences that it understands are those given in the `xterm` entry/entries in the termcap/terminfo database.)  So too, nowadays, does the terminal emulator in the FreeBSD virtual console.  The terminal emulator in the Linux virtual console is in fact a slightly different terminal type, designated `linux`.  (This used to be the case for the FreeBSD virtual console, too, which had a `cons25` type.  FreeBSD changed its kernel terminal emulator to be xterm-compatible in version 9.0, as part of a project to get UTF-8 support on virtual consoles.)  All of these xterm-alikes, and the Linux kernel terminal emulator, have the full settable hard tabs mechanism.

(For those who enjoy reading the source: Look at the `TabNext()` and `TabToNextStop()` functions in `tabs.c` in the `xterm` source code.)

You can try it for yourself.  Run these commands:

```
tbc=$(tput tbc) hts=$(tput hts)
printf '%s\r%s\r\n' "${tbc}" "a${hts}aaa${hts}aaaaaaa${hts}aaaaaaaaaaaaa${hts}aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa${hts}"
```

Then run your command again.  Exactly *five* tabstops have been set.  Count the `${hts}` in the command, or look at the line of `a` characters.  Beyond the fifth, the `TAB` character causes that metaphorical typewriter carriage to whizz all of the rest of the way over to the right-hand margin.

The next (printing, non-`TAB`) character causes an *automatic* carriage return to the left margin, and linefeed to the next line.  In termcap/terminfo terminology, the `xterm` terminal type has *automatic margins*.  In theory, Unix and Linux can work with terminals that do not have automatic margins.  Your `printf` command would get stuck at column 79, not matter how much more you output, until you wrote a carriage return.  In practice, such a device would boggle the minds of most people nowadays.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to me, the settable TAB offers the capacity of building a spreadsheet software on console. But none were found mature - I used one such opensource tool a few years ago with poor quality, name forgotten.

Comment: By the way, I actually have a console, a real one with embedded Chinese font and Z-80 CPU, with me since 1997, although I did not dust it off to test this tab-stop case.

Comment: That answer should be in the Hacker's Dictionary appendix. I somehow got here while researching [elastic tabstops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/) and [secrets of tabs in vim](https://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html) - worth it 100%. I remember the feeling to having to having to input *actual physical energy* into the surelevated top-right TAB key on an Olympia typewriter.