# Last tabulator (tab) character not jumping to next line in terminal

Tags: terminal

I have run into a problem. In my case it was a Lua program printing a series of numbers. Lua uses tabs as the separators, and the output came out like this in my 80-column terminal:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      1
1      12
```

Note how the number 11 is truncated, with the first 1 at column 79 and the second 1 at column 0 of the next ine. I expected the complete number 11 to appear in the next line instead.

It's not Lua-specific, and is easily reproducible with this one-liner:

```
printf '1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12'
```

I have read this question and the accepted answer: [Why there are 11 tabstops on a 80-column console?](https://superuser.com/questions/710019/why-there-are-11-tabstops-on-a-80-column-console) which made me understand *why* that is happening. The question is, is there a way to override that behaviour, to make the last tab jump to column 0 in the next line, rather than to the last column in the current line?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot make this work automatically, i.e., without filtering the output from your program to interpret tab at the right-margin as wrapping.  That is because VT100-style wrapping gets up to the right-margin, and will **not** wrap unless you write a *printable* character.  Tabs are not printable.

Most terminals are setup to use soft tabs (already expanded to spaces).  You could check your `stty` settings to see if this is so.  The output is obscure, but `tab0` means that it tries to use tabs, while `tab3` says it does not.

To see the setting:

```
stty -a
```

To disable hard-tabs:

```
stty -tabs
```

Lua *may* override that setting, but if it does not, it is a possibility since <kbd>space</kbd> is a printable character.

Further reading:

- [That description of wrapping is odd, say more?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#vt100_wrapping) (xterm FAQ)
- [Examples of wrapping](http://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest-wrap.html) (vttest)

Comment: But isn't there a non-VT100-style terminal type and/or terminal program that explicitly disobeys that rule? The rule sounds pretty useless, confusing and tied to the past.

Comment: That's the part you're intended to read ("Further reading").  The q/a which you cited is not useful to me.

Comment: I've read it, but it doesn't answer the question. I've tried xvt, rxvt, mrxvt, konsole, pterm, lxterminal, xfce4-terminal, screen, and xterm. Each and every one of them behaved the same when entering the printf line above. The question is if there's one that doesn't, or if there's a terminal type or terminal program that is deliberately not VT100-compatible in that respect.

Comment: Print a long line using spaces (say 90) and an asterisk.  That should wrap.  Doing the same with tabs will not.